# How to check if a value have specific text in it

Tags: excel, vba

I have an sheet with over 1000 rows. In column A I have a text like

```
:IO.Tgr37.Tank37.TT
```

In sheet "innstiilinger" in column F, I have a bunch of keywords to look for,
like Tgr37 on row7 and Tgr10 on row8

In column G I have

```
Tgr 120, Tgr 600.......
```

If the text has Tgr37 or Tgr10 in it I would like to add a prefix to the text.
If the text has Tgr120 or Tgr600 in it I would add another prefix to the text..

I tried this code:

```
Dim sCellVal As String
sCellVal = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value

Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
FindString = sCellVal

If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
With Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("F:F") 'searches all of column F
    Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        tag_opc.Value = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("F6") & Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & ".Value" 'value found
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing found" 'value not found
    End If
End With
End If
```

but it do not work, when I put my keyword in column A and the text in column F in sheet "innstillinger" it works.

Sorry for my bad English but I hope you understand my problem...
Excel 2013

Answer (score 0):

Where are you declaring the `tag_opc` object?

Anyway, the `.Find` method is a poor choice to use for operations like this. The most efficient way to perform what you're doing is to lift your data into an array (or arrays), process what you need to process, then transpose the results back to where they need to go.

To make things a little easier to follow, though, I'll suggest an option B, which is to use a `For Each` loop over the range in question instead.

```
Dim sCellVal As String
Dim wsReference As Excel.Worksheet

Set wsReference = Worksheets(1) 'or refer to this by name
sCellVal = wsReference.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value

Dim wsSearch As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set wsSearch = Worksheets(2) 'or refer to this by name
Set rng = wsSearch.Range("F:F")

If Trim(Len(sCellVal)) <> 0 Then

    For Each cell In rng

        'Perform actions

    Next cell

End If
```

This should cover the core of what you would need to do.  However, I would swap out the `ActiveCell` for a more specific reference, since anything `active` in VBA is notoriously finicky.  You can use a loop, for example, to increment an `i` value upward through each iteration.

Its a little ambiguous as to what you want to do here, though.  You refer to "text" multiple times, but don't clarify which "text" you're referring to.

Can you provide Before and After examples?  We'll probably be able to provide a better answer if we can see specifically what you're looking to do.

Comment: The text i am refering to is opc tags from a plc program. I am going to import the tags to a historylogger software, but the tags are not complete. I need to add some extra text to the tags, and what text i need to add depends on what "Tgrxx" it belongs to. So i wanted list the different Tgr that need "text1" added to the opc-tag in coloum F (this is about 10 different Tgr) and Tgr that need "text2" added are listed in coloum G.... and so on..

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all sorts of trick today, i was close,but no... I have deleted all and got back to start. This is my code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


'Autofyll userform
nr = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D8")
tag_opc.Value = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
unit.Value = Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
min.Value = Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
max.Value = Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
io.Value = Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
ioType = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
tagnavn = Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
Register = Range("L" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
test2 = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("F9").Value



If Register = "registrert" Then
  MsgBox "Denne er allerede registrert", vbExclamation, "kritisk feil"
  Unload Me
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
    Tagimport.Show
  End

End If


'Autofullfør Prefix og Suffix til tag

Dim sCellVal As String
sCellVal = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value    

If sCellVal Like "*Tgr10*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr15*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr17*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr37*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr40x*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr70x*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr85*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr90*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr91*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr100*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr104*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr105*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr110*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr115*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr118*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr120x*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr128x*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr135*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr176*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr180x*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*TgrROx*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Past1*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Past3*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Past4x*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Past5*" Then

    tag_opc.Value = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("F6") & Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & ".Value" 'String henta ifrå innstillinger F6

    ElseIf sCellVal Like "*Past6x*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Past7*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Past904*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*MMS*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Servicex*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr900*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr910*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr915*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr920*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*L952LIS*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*L952M2*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*T172BTU1*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*T172BFT1*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*T172Bph1*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*T172BTT1*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Myse*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Motorhead*" Then

    tag_opc.Value = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("G6") & Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & ".Value" 'String henta ifrå innstillinger G6

ElseIf sCellVal Like "*Tgr170*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr171*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr173*" Then

        tag_opc.Value = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("H6") & Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & ".Value" 'String henta ifrå innstillinger H6

ElseIf sCellVal Like "*Pasteur1*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Pasteur2*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Pasteur3*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Pasteur4*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Pasteur15*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*SmørSmelter*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*EksterneSystem*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Trykk_Isvann*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Trykk_Luft*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Vannmåler*" Then

    tag_opc.Value = "OPC::Text3:" & Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & ".Value"


ElseIf sCellVal Like "*Pasteur11*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Pasteur12*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr65*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr70*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr75*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr145*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr166*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr180*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr211*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr244*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*TgrRO*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Inndamper*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*T167*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Nivå_BT_Tapp2*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "FilterElveVannFeil*" Then

    tag_opc.Value = "OPC::Text4:" & Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & ".Value"

ElseIf sCellVal Like "*Tgr20*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr25*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr28*" Or _
        sCellVal Like "*Tgr150*" Then

    tag_opc.Value = "OPC::Text5:" & Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & ".Value"
Else

MsgBox "Finner ingen plassering" 'Kan ikkje plassere i program

End If
 ' Next cell
'fyll inn dropdownliste engineering unit

With unit
.AddItem "g/cm3"
     .AddItem "µS/cm"
     .AddItem "liter"
     .AddItem "%"
     .AddItem "m³/t"
     .AddItem "l/t"
     .AddItem "°C"
     .AddItem "mBar"
     .AddItem "Bar"
     .AddItem "Ph"
     .AddItem "ms"
     .AddItem "m³"
End With


'Sjekker om det er analog eller digital logging

    If ioType = "AnalogSignalIn" Then
        Analog.Value = True
            ElseIf ioType = "analogsignalIn" Then
                Analog.Value = True
            ElseIf ioType = "analogsignalin" Then
                Analog.Value = True
            ElseIf ioType = "Analogsignalin" Then
                Analog.Value = True
            ElseIf ioType = "AnalogSignalOut" Then
                Analog.Value = True
            ElseIf ioType = "analogsignalout" Then
                Analog.Value = True
            ElseIf ioType = "AnalogSignalout" Then
                Analog.Value = True
            ElseIf ioType = "BooleanSignal" Then
                Digital.Value = True
            ElseIf ioType = "booleansignal" Then
                Digital.Value = True
            ElseIf ioType = "booleanSignal" Then
                Digital.Value = True
            Else
                MsgBox "Det må velges analog eller digitalt signal", vbExclamation, "kritisk feil"
    End If


'Sett markør i Tagnamn hvis denne er tom

    If tagnavn = "" Then
        tagnavn.SetFocus
    End If



End Sub



Private Sub Reg_Click()
'

If tagnavn.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Denne har ingen TAG", vbExlamation, "dette går ikkje"
    tagnavn.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

'Aktiver data-arket

'Velge kor data skal plasserast, analog eller digital

If Analog = True Then


            If unit.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Dette er ein analog verdi, vennligst velg ein måleenhet", vbExlamation, "dette går ikkje"
            unit.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
            End If

            Sheets(2).Activate
            Range("A3").EntireRow.Insert
            Active_Row = 3

            'Fylle inn i kolonner

            Range("A" & Active_Row) = meierinr + "_" + tagnavn             '(AnalogTag)TagName"
            Range("B" & Active_Row) = beskrivelse                          'Description
            Range("C" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D9")  'IOServerComputerName
            Range("D" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D10") 'IOServerAppName
            Range("E" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D11") 'TopicName
            Range("F" & Active_Row) = tag_opc.Value                        'ItemName
            Range("G" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D12") 'AcquisitionType
            Range("H" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D13") 'StorageType
            Range("I" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D14") 'AcquisitionRate
            Range("J" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D14") 'StorageRate
            Range("K" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D15") 'TimeDeadband
            Range("L" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D16") 'SamplesInAI
            Range("M" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D17") 'AIMode
            Range("N" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D18") 'EngUnits
            Range("O" & Active_Row) = min                                  'MinEU
            Range("P" & Active_Row) = max                                  'MaxEU
            Range("Q" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D19")  'MinRaw
            Range("R" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D20")  'MaxRaw
            Range("S" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D21")  'Scaling
            Range("T" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D22")  'RawType
            Range("U" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D23")  'IntegerSize
            Range("V" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D24")  'Sign
            Range("W" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D25")  'ValueDeadband
            Range("X" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D26")  'InitialValue
            Range("Y" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D27")  'CurrentEditor
            Range("Z" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D28")  'RateDeadband
            Range("AA" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D29") 'InterpolationType
            Range("AB" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D30") 'RolloverValue
            Range("AC" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D31") 'ServerTimeStamp
            Range("AD" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D32") 'DeadbandType
            Range("AE" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D33") 'TagId
            Range("AF" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D34") 'ChannelStatus
            Range("AG" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D35") 'AITag
            Range("AH" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D36") 'AIHistory


ElseIf Digital = True Then
    Sheets(2).Activate
    Active_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

                        'Fylle inn i kolonner

            Range("A" & Active_Row) = meierinr + "_" + tagnavn             ':(DiscreteTag)TagName
            Range("B" & Active_Row) = beskrivelse                          'Description
            Range("C" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D9")  'IOServerComputerName
            Range("D" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D10") 'IOServerAppName
            Range("E" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D11") 'TopicName
            Range("F" & Active_Row) = tag_opc.Value                        'ItemName
            Range("G" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D12") 'AcquisitionType
            Range("H" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D13") 'StorageType
            Range("I" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D14") 'AcquisitionRate
            Range("J" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D15") 'TimeDeadband
            Range("K" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D16") 'SamplesInAI
            Range("L" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D17") 'AIMode
            Range("M" & Active_Row) = "0"                                  'Message0
            Range("N" & Active_Row) = "1"                                  'Message1
            Range("O" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D26") 'InitialValue
            Range("P" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D27") 'CurrentEditor
            Range("Q" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D31") 'ServerTimeStamp
            Range("R" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D33") 'TagId
            Range("S" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D34") 'ChannelStatus
            Range("T" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D35") 'AITag
            Range("U" & Active_Row) = Sheets("Innstillinger").Range("D36") 'AIHistory




Else
    MsgBox "Her har du ikkje følgt med, det må velges analogt eller digitalt signal!!!", vbExclamation, "GAPELESTE"
    Analog.SetFocus
    End
End If


Sheets(1).Activate


 'ActiveCell.Markere Tag som registrert.
Range("L" & ActiveCell.Row) = "registrert"

'oppdaterer regnearket
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

Unload Me

Tagimport.Show


End Sub

Private Sub Neste_Click()
 Unload Me
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
    Tagimport.Show
End Sub


Private Sub Avbryt_Click()
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

I want to get the part where i am listing up the different text to search for out on the sheet, not in the code.

The before is like this: IO.Tgr10.F182PT1
After should be like this: OPC::Text2:IO.Tgr10.F182PT1.Value

If before is like this: IO.Tgr150.F152PT1 
After should be like this : OPC::Text5:IO.Tgr150.F152PT1.Value